# Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Although I saw some other posts with people having the same issue, I didn't find any other case that's similar to mine.

I have this block of code where I need to split an object in 4 parts:

```
  const eventsLastAddedLine1: EventsListType["events"] =
    eventsLastadded &&
    Object.entries(eventsLastadded?.data)
      .slice(0, 4)
      .map((entry) => entry[1]);
```

That code is working well but Typescript is warning this (about `eventsLastAddedLine1`) in VS Code:

```
Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; attributes: { slug: string; name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date; }; }[]'.
```

If I leave the mouse over `eventsLastAddedLine1` (to see its type definition), looks correct:

```
const eventsLastAddedLine1: {
    id: number;
    attributes: {
        slug: string;
        name: string;
        startDate: Date;
        endDate: Date;
    };
}[]
```

My definition for `EventsListType` is the following:

```
export type EventsListType = {
  events: { id: number; attributes: { slug: string; name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date } }[];
  isReady: boolean;
};
```

I'm not a Typescript expert (still learning), so I can't find where is the problem. How can I fix it? Thank you!

EDIT:

This is where `eventsLastadded` comes from:

```
const { data: eventsLastadded } = useSWR(`/events?${queryLastAdded}`, swrFetcher);
```

The `data` above has the following type:

```
SWRResponse<any, any>.data?: any
```

Comment: Do you know the type definition for `eventsLastadded`?

Comment: @hawschiat I've just updated the post including the information about eventsLastadded

Comment: Thanks! Does the `useSWR` hook come from [`vercel/swr`](https://github.com/vercel/swr)?

Comment: @hawschiat yeah

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva sorry, I missed the `[]` at the end that makes it an array

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [type definition for `useSWR` hook](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/9a7c76870e4bdc806e44de06e86abe3c2e40fb56/src/types.ts#L85-L116), you can type cast the response to `EventsListType["events"][]` by passing it as a generic type parameter like this:

```
const { data: eventsLastadded } = useSWR<EventsListType["events"][]>(`/events?${queryLastAdded}`, swrFetcher);

// eventsLastadded is typecasted as EventsListType["events"][] | undefined
```